# Semantic UI (React) Grid centering issue

Tags: grid, semantic-ui, centering

I'm trying to center a child (horizontally and vertically) in its parent in a Grid layout.
I don't want to use tricks like

`top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`

because this does not use the Grid properties and creates problems for animations.

It should be pretty easy but i'm not able to do it...

Can you help me?

https://codesandbox.io/s/qkyv1v8oq6

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the parent in a flex is always a block element (if you do not state differently), so it is ok to assign it: `margin: 0 auto;`and that's all